# Data POST'd to Cake controller is not being bound to the variable of the function

Tags: php, json, cakephp, controller

```
$.post("http://localhost/academico/materias/getid",
       ui.item.value,
       function(data){
           console.log(data);
       }, "json");
```

In my controller the `$data` variable is always null:

```
// $data is always null. How come?
public function getid($data = null) {
    debug($data);
    // Como vamos a retornar solamente datos, no necesitamos el layout.
    $this->layout = null;

    $this->set('data', $data);
    $this->render('/Elements/ajaxreturn');
}
```

How can I get the value POST'd to be bound to something I can use in the Controller code?

Comment: @MoyedAnsari: That just returns 'array()'.

Comment: does console.log(data) show something ?

Comment: @MoyedAnsari: It doesn't show anything, it seems the function(data) method never enters.

Comment: it means there is a problem in ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define the $data variable as a parameter to the function, that expects it to be present in the URL. POST data is automatically populated in the Request object.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-post-data

"All POST data can be accessed using CakeRequest::$data. Any form data that contains a data prefix, will have that data prefix removed."

```
$this->request->data
```